# Connection to the server x.y.z.w was refused did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, devops, minikube

I have downloaded/installed Kubernetes, Virtual Box and MiniKube. Later, I started minikube on VM. When I try running kubectl version command from my terminal I receive the below error message. Could anybody tell me what is the reason behind this error. I have explored everywhere but I couldn't find right resolution for this problem. I am new to this and just taking baby steps. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
The connection to the server 192.168.99.100:8443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could anybody tell me what is the reason behind this error

It is because your `kubectl` configuration file, housed at `$HOME/.kube/config`, points at that IP address and port but there is nothing listening on that IP and port.

Using the `minikube status` command will tell you what it thinks is going on, and `minikube ssh` will place you inside the virtual machine and allow you to look around for yourself, which can be helpful to get the docker logs to say why there is nothing listening on the port you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is to run `minikube ip` and see if it matches the IP address kubectl is expecting (as seen in the error message). If not, update your kubeconfig accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
minikube ssh
```

and then

```
journalctl -u kubelet
```

The above should provide you with additional information about why the server is refusing connections.

---

This answer might also be helpful: [How to diagnose Kubernetes not responding on API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638559/how-to-diagnose-kubernetes-not-responding-on-api)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running behind a proxy, make sure to export the NO_PROXY env variable or permanently set it in your `/etc/environment` file.

```
export NO_PROXY=192.168.99.0/24,127.0.0.1,...
```